# postback in asp doesn't refresh control value

Tags: asp.net

I have a div(runat=server) that contain repeater,this repeater is getting is value from datatable

when the datatable is empty I do this line of code in asp .net function

```
divname.innerHTML="<img src="...>"
```

on this page there is also a asp:button that fill the datatable with values.
when pressing the button ,the above line isn't excute,the page offcourse is doing postback, but the div content isn't changing back to his original value(the repeater).

What do I have to do in the postback in order to force the div to get his original values?

This is code example:

```
     sub page_load(..
if ispostback=false then
         run_div()
end if
        end sub

        sub run_div()

    if datatable.Rows.Count=0 then
    divname.innerHTML="<img src="...>"


    end if
    end sub


sub filldata(....

fill datatable
 repeater.datasource=...
    repeater.databind
run_div()

end sub



    html look like this

    <div runat=servver id=divname><asp:repeater>.....
    <asp:button onclick="filldata">
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the variable named datatable is a System.Data.DataTable, remember that it only exists and had data in the context of a sibgle run of the page lifecycle.  if the page is re-generated (whether it's via a postback or an initial load of the page) the DataTable is empty until it's loaded.

However, the Repeater object is stored in teh ViewState.  IT will have values on a postback if there were rows on the previous load.

Instead of looking at the number of rows in the table, you should be looking at the Repteater.Items.Count.

```
If repeater.Items.Count = 0 Then
   divname.innerHTML="<img src="...>"    
Else
   ...
End If
```

Comment: no,no you right, I forget to mention ,there is a a postback check in the page load

Comment: OK.  I think you can ignore everything but the third point.  I re-read your code sample again and the first two really don't apply so I'm going to delete them.  I think the third point hits the correct issue.

Comment: Edited to remove irrelevant points and clarify what I think is the relevant point.

Comment: your suggestions are very right ,but this is just example code,there is a reason for this to work like this it's not necessarily mean that the code isn't right(just the postback check in the page_load),but why the div content is not changing to orignal values after postback?

Comment: Your point is clear to me ,the button event happen after the page_load so the datatable is emtpy when the page loads but your suggestion isn't slove this matter

Comment: adding this row to the end of the button event slove this problem:Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) and store the datatable in session too